# glGetTexImage/glGetCompressedTexImage and sRGB colorspace

Tags: opengl

When I use sRGB internal format, for example `GL_SRGB8_EXT` or `GL_COMPRESSED_SRGB_S3TC_DXT1_EXT` as `glTexImage2D` argument I get an automatic sRGB to lRGB conversion when reading a texture in the shader. Does `glGetTexImage/glGetCompressedTexImage` also perform such conversion ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `glGetTexImage/glGetCompressedTexImage` do not perform sRGB conversion. Neither does `glTexImage2D`. If you set a texture image with `glTexImage2D` and later retrieve it with `glGetTexImage` (using same format and type), you'll read back the same data that you passed to `glTexImage2D` at the start. It doesn't matter if texture's internal format was `GL_SRGB8` or `GL_RGB8`.

sRGB ↔ linear conversion is a server-side operation, i.e. performed by operations on the GPU.
sRGB to linear conversion happens only when the GPU reads from the texture (from shaders, `glBlitFramebuffer`, etc). Linear to sRGB conversion happens only when the GPU writes to a texture (through `imageStore`, FBO, `glBlitFramebuffer`, etc). Consequently if you render linear data to an sRGB texture, **then** `glGetTexImage` will return sRGB data. However the conversion is done when your render to the texture, not in the `glGetTexImage` call.